# (PHP) List of Cities by user input

Tags: php, geocoding, openstreetmap, city

I need a free *(and maybe an open-source)* service to get a list of cities *(towns, villages, hamlets)*, with some data like:
 - geoCoords [LAT|LON] //very important!!
 - district
 - region/county
 - state
 - (maybe zipcode)

The user types his place of residence in an input field and get a list of cities from which he/she can choose his own city. (maybe displaying with some infos like county or state or whatever) - And I need to save the geoCoords [LAT|LON] into my database for calculating distances to other users later.

So I found the OpenStreetMap - project: `http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=`**Neustadt**`&format=json&addressdetails=1` *([example](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Neustadt&format=xml&addressdetails=1))*

This looks fine, but I need a way to filter the results. Because I don't need bus/rail stations or shopping malls. Only locations/settlements *(cities/towns, villages/suburbs/hamlets)* where people live. And - if it's possible - also filtered by country *(in this case: Germany)*.

Does anyone have some ideas? :)

Comment: I use Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: `&featuretype=settlement`. Other possible values for featuretype are: `country`, `state`, `city`.

Comment: I can't use googleMaps, cos maybe I'll have more than 5'000 page impressions each day. With more than 5 hits to the API could cost a lot of money. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Nominatim documentation in the OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). Instead of using simple queries try *structured requests*:

- This query will will return all kinds of cities, towns, villages and suburbs with the name *Neustadt*: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?city=Neustadt
- You can also provie more parameters, for example the country: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?city=Neustadt&country=Deutschland

Note that you *can't* combine a structured query with the `q=<query>` parameter.

And please comply with [Nominatim's usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy), this service runs on donated resources and has limited capacity. If you need to run more frequent queries then either choose one of the alternative instances or [install and run your own instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation).

Comment: I don't see a difference between the url-attributed queries. :/ Maybe I use my old idea: just a hand writed list of towns/counties with special informations like state/country/... :/

Comment: So I found this list (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Städte_in_Deutschland) of towns/cities/counties in Germany (with notes to the state, inside the parentheses). - But just without GeoCoords [LAT|LON]. :/

Comment: Sorry... with GeoCoords [LAT|LON] (little bit hidden at the upper right corner of the wiki detail page). :)

Comment: I didn't quite understand why this doesn't work for you. But great that you found an alternative.